# How to Write below SQL Query in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
SELECT * FROM vnfconfigdetails where vnfid='1234' and (creationdate >= '2018-07-12' and creationdate <= '2018-07-15');
```

I have try bellow JPA query but empty result coming.

```
@Query(value= " SELECT * FROM vnfconfigdetails where (creationdate >= :startDate AND creationdate <= :endDate ) AND vnfid =:vnfid", nativeQuery = true)
List<VnfConfigDetailsDB> findByVnfidAndCreationdate(@Param("vnfid") String vnfid,@Param("startDate") Date startDate, @Param("endDate")Date endDate);
```

ShowSQL Query-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vnfconfigdetails", schema = "testreports")
public class VnfConfigDetailsDB {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "vnfid")
    private String vnfid;

    @Column(name = "vnfversion")
    private String vnfversion;

    @Column(name = "vnfname")
    private String vnfname;

    @Column(name = "configinfo")
    @Lob
    private String configinfo;

    @Column(name = "creationdate")
    private Date creationdate;

    @Column(name = "lastupdated")
    private Date lastupdated;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getVnfid() {
        return vnfid;
    }

    public void setVnfid(String vnfid) {
        this.vnfid = vnfid;
    }

    public String getVnfversion() {
        return vnfversion;
    }

    public void setVnfversion(String vnfversion) {
        this.vnfversion = vnfversion;
    }

    public String getVnfname() {
        return vnfname;
    }

    public void setVnfname(String vnfname) {
        this.vnfname = vnfname;
    }

    public String getConfiginfo() {
        return configinfo;
    }

    public void setConfiginfo(String configinfo) {
        this.configinfo = configinfo;
    }

    public Date getCreationdate() {
        return creationdate;
    }

    public void setCreationdate(Date creationdate) {
        this.creationdate = creationdate;
    }


    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }



    public Date getLastupdated() {
        return lastupdated;
    }

    public void setLastupdated(Date lastupdated) {
        this.lastupdated = lastupdated;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
 List<VnfConfigDetailsDB> findByVnfidAndCreationdateBetween(String vnfid, Date startDate, Date endDate)
```

You don't need `@Query`. When you say Between, sping-data will formulate the query correctly.

Comment: Thank You it's working fine.And i have made other query's also like this

Answer (score 0):

In your case you use native query. This is not JPQL so you have to do some changes.

1. Do not use @Param infront of parameters in the method: Please remove @Param("vnfid"), @Param("startDate") and @Param("endDate").
2. Replace all :paramName with ?. For example replace :startDate with ?NumberOfParam and so on inside of the query:

   ```
   @Query(value= " SELECT * FROM vnfconfigdetails where (creationdate >= ?2 AND   creationdate <= ?3 ) AND vnfid =?1", nativeQuery = true)
   List<VnfConfigDetailsDB> findByVnfidAndCreationdate(String vnfid,Date startDate, Date endDate);
   ```

If you want to use JPQL then you have to remove nativeQuery = true and your query will look something like that:

```
@Query(value= " SELECT v FROM VnfConfigDetailsDB v where (v.creationdate >= :startDate AND v.creationdate <= :endDate ) AND v.vnfid =:vnfid")
List<VnfConfigDetailsDB> findByVnfidAndCreationdate(@Param("vnfid") String vnfid,@Param("startDate") Date startDate, @Param("endDate")Date endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove @Param

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM vnfconfigdetails where (creationdate >= ?2 AND   creationdate <= ?3 ) AND vnfid =?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<VnfConfigDetailsDB> findByVnfidAndCreationdateBetween(String vnfid, Date startDate, Date endDate);
```

In the entity class add the temporal annotation. This annotation must be specified for persistent fields or properties of type java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar. It may only be specified for fields or properties of these types.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "creationdate", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
private Date creationdate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "lastupdated", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
private Date lastupdated;
```